# Failed to capture microphone input using pulseaudio as a systemd unit

Tags: linux, go, systemd, pulseaudio

I created a small go program that uses [these](https://github.com/mesilliac/pulse-simple) go bindings to record some commands from the default microphone and act accordingly. It works fine as a standalone binary(both as normal user and root user) but when I tried to convert it into a systemd unit the `Capture` function in the go bindings failed with error saying `connection refused`.

The program is failing to capture the microphone input when running as a systemd service. The following is the unit file which is pretty much copy-pasted from [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Examples).

```
[Unit]
Description=Commander service providing voice commands

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/binary/binary.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

binary.sh is a simple shell script that for providing environment variables to the go binary. The script is below

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/binary
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./binary > stdout 2> stderr
```

The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is needed for `pocketsphinx` shared libraries which is being used for recognizing commands from audio.

I think something is wrong with the unit file but I don't know what it is. The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/farkaskid/commander).

Any insight would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: PulseAudio generally runs in the context of the logged in user's session, and audio input/output is only possible for programs running inside that session. It should not be possible for a system service to obtain microphone audio from PulseAudio running in a user's session, as that would be a serious security breach.

Comment: Hi, Michael. That makes a lot of sense. But it should be possible to run a service in user's session using `systemd`..? or do I have to use desktop environment's autostart mechanism to achieve what I want..?

Comment: systemd services never run in a user's desktop session.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for the DE's autostart mechanism then.

Comment: It sounds like this would make sense to run as a systemd user service (just like PulseAudio itself).

Comment: Thanks @LucasWerkmeister, I'll look into it.

Comment: @LucasWerkmeister It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

pulseaudio is a daemon which probably has yet to get launched ... update your `binary.sh` with a

```
sleep 10
echo about to determine whether pulseaudio is up and running
pulseaudio --check
echo if pulseaudio is running above check silently returns
```

prior to launching your golang binary

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the input but `pulseaudio` is running. I'm testing the service side-by-side with the binary. The binary is running but the service is giving me problems. I'll add this check though once this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is required to set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environmental variable to directory `/run/user/<USER_ID>`, e.g.

```
[Service]
Environment="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001"
ExecStart=/path/to/binary/binary.sh
```